# NoReverseMatch at /mypage/

Tags: python, django

I am creating a mypage which allows see and update user info. But it seems that mypage.html doesn't recieve user_detail and user_update, since the error message says 'NoReverseMatch at /mypage/
Reverse for 'user_detail' with arguments '(None,)' not found.'

url

```
path('mypage/', views.MypageView.as_view(), name='mypage'),
path('user_detail/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
path('user_update/<int:pk>/', views.UserUpdate.as_view(), name='user_update'),
```

views.py

```
class UserDetail(OnlyYouMixin, generic.DetailView):
  model = User
  template_name = 'perotta/user_detail.html'

class UserUpdate(OnlyYouMixin, generic.UpdateView):
  model = User
  form_class = UserUpadateForm
  template_name = 'perotta/user_form.html'

  def get_success_url(self):
    return resolve_url('perotta:user_detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])


class MypageView(generic.TemplateView):
  template_name = 'perotta/mypage.html'
```

mypage.html

```
{% extends "perotta/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="{% url 'perotta:user_detail' user.pk %}">ユーザー情報閲覧</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="{% url 'perotta:user_update' user.pk %}">ユーザー情報更新</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

sorry, since the website is for the Japanese,  it may contains Japanese words. I'm new to programing, so I would really appreciate how to solve this.

Comment: You are not passing anything on `MypageView`'s context

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates.

Comment: @JPG `user` should always be available if `auth` context processor is installed.

Comment: It's now solved. The problem was that I didn't login in, so that I had nothing to pass, I guess. I really appreciate what you guys have given me!!